# Keyframes to actions

Tags: animation, keyframes, actions

I'm quite new to blender. Is there an easy way in blender 2.8 to make an animation of keyframes into animation with actions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, it's not clear, could you please give more explanations?

Comment: Hi. Could you give some information on why you think you need this? Thanks.

Comment: Hi guys, I made an animations in blender with keyframes and curvatures. The problem now when exporting this to fbx, the animation in unity is totally different than in blender. My idea was to make actions in this animation to prevent the animation of changing. But i'm not sure this is possible or do i need to start all over again to make actions.